# Slim SessionCookie middleware not working

Tags: php, session-cookies, middleware, slim

This is my index.php

```
<?php
$app = new \Slim\Slim(
    array(
        'templates.path' => dirname(__FILE__).'/templates'
    )
);

// Add session cookie middle-ware. Shouldn't this create a cookie?
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\SessionCookie());

// Add a custom middle-ware
$app->add(new \CustomMiddleware());

$app->get(
    '/', 
    function () use ($app) {
        $app->render('Home.php');
    }
);

$app->run();
?>
```

This is my custom middle-ware:

```
<?php
class CustomMiddleware extends \Slim\Middleware {
    public function call() {
        // This session variable should be saved
        $_SESSION['test'] = 'Hello!';

        $this->next->call();
    }
}
?>
```

And this is my template (*Home.php*)

```
<?php
var_dump($_SESSION['test']);
?>
```

which will output NULL, so the session variable is not saved. Also, when opening the cookies list in the navigator I don't see any. Why isn't the cookie of the session saved? I verified and made sure that the `call()` function of the `SessionCookie` class is executed.

Comment: I haven't used slim before, but it may be a simple case of declaring `session_start();` before setting any variables.

Comment: can you determine the order of call method invocation SessionCookie vs CustomMiddleware ? looked at the source code https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/blob/master/Slim/Middleware/SessionCookie.php#L132 and it seems if the cookie is not set $_SESSION is reset.

Comment: I have found this line: `ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);`. Look like the use of cookies is disabled. CustomMiddleware is called before SessionCookie but even if I call it after, the session will not persist after I refresh

Comment: have you solved? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How if you add your `CustomMiddleware` first before `Slim\Middleware\SessionCookie`?

Something like this:

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';

Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

class CustomMiddleware extends Slim\Middleware
{
    public function call() {
        // This session variable should be saved
        $_SESSION['test'] = 'Hello!';

        $this->next->call();
    }
}

$app = new Slim\Slim();

$app->add(new CustomMiddleware());

$app->add(new Slim\Middleware\SessionCookie());

// GET route
$app->get('/', function () use ($app)
{
    $app->render('home.php');
});

$app->run();
```

And your `home.php` template file:

```
<?php echo($_SESSION['test']); ?>
```

For me, it works flawlessly. But if I add `Slim\Middleware\SessionCookie` before my `CustomMiddleware`, the output of `$_SESSION['test']` remains `NULL`.

This is how middleware works:

[image: Middleware]

So, your response will never get any `$_SESSION` value, since you set your `$_SESSION` before `SessionCookie` called.